# SparkStreaming textFileStreaming doesn't give output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, cloudera

I'm trying to make wordcount example using streaming from a text file, the problem is **word.print()** doesn't show the result, anything but the timestamp

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1509542480000 ms
-------------------------------------------
```

I'm moving the file while the application is running, and the path is correct to the destination folder "words", here's my code

```
object StreamingWordCount {

def main(args: Array[String]) {

   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Application").setMaster("local[*]")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
   val lines = ssc.textFileStream("/home/cloudera/Desktop/words/")

val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    words.print()

   ssc.start()
   ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

  }
```

I'm on Cloudera environment, Spark 1.6, Scala 10.6

Comment: The timestamp proves that the application at least started processing which is good. How do you "moving the file while the application is running"? What's the command? Files must be written to the monitored directory by "moving" them from another location within the same file system. Use `mv`. File names starting with . are ignored.

Comment: I was using drag and drop, i used mv now and have same problem. the file is on Desktop and the destination that the file moves to is on Desktop too.

Comment: Can you do `echo hello world > /home/cloudera/Desktop/words/hello.txt` while the app is up and running?